# Paypal Payflow: Receive COMMENT1 and COMMENT2 information an a confirmation email

Tags: php, paypal

I asked another question that I think might be misleading, as I'm not sure it can actually be done with silent post.

In the payflow, there are custom tags COMMENT1 and COMMENT2, which appear in the transaction if I log into manager.paypal.com.

I want to know if there is a way (and how) to have that information, COMMENT1 and COMMENT2, also sent in an email when a transaction is completed. I know that it cannot be 'added' to the confirmation email sent by paypal, but perhaps it could be generated at the same time??

Very new to php and this type of coding-- so please, basic explanations. Thanks so much.

-Shawn

Edit:

I was told that I can use silent post, and based on Andrew's first response perhaps. The current code I have is:

```
<?php
//PLACE EMAIL BELOW:
$email="myemail@myemaildomain.com"; 
$req = "";
if ($_POST) 
{
// iterate through each name value pair
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
//write to file
$fh = fopen("logpost.txt", 'a');//open file and create if does not exist
fwrite($fh, "\r\n/////////////////////////////////////////\r\n");//Just for spacing in log file
fwrite($fh, $req);//write data
fclose($fh);//close file

//Email
$mail_From = "From: SilentPost@tester.com";
$mail_To = $email;
$mail_Subject = "POST EXISTS";
$mail_Body = $req;
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

//

//if posted return echo response
echo $req;
}

// No post data received
if (empty($_POST)) 
{
//write to file
$fh = fopen("logpost.txt", 'a');//open file and create if does not exist
fwrite($fh, "\r\n/////////////////////////////////////////\r\n");//Just for spacing in log file
fwrite($fh, "Empty Post");//write data
fclose($fh);//close file

//Email
$mail_From = "From: SilentPost@tester.com";
$mail_To = $email;
$mail_Subject = "Empty Post";
$mail_Body = "";
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

//if posted return echo response
echo "Empty Post";
}

?>
```

So, I'm not quite sure how to get those to be sent - but it seems Andrew might.

Comment: Please contact the vendor of that service for your support options. You're basically asking for a set of features which means, those are documented or not. If documented, please refer to the documentation. You are required to do so before posting your question here (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If it's not documented, please first of all contact the vendor for your support options in case of undocumented functionality. Undocumented functionality - if not obvious material - tend to change to quick and be too limited for general purpose on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the Silent POST from PayFlow isn't including the COMMENT parameters by default, what you could do is run an Inquiry request within your Silent POST script that hits PayFlow to pull the transaction details.  That response should include more detail like the comments.

Comment: Thanks Andrew -- unfortunately I am not quite sure how to do that. Could you explain a bit more? I am very new to php, or perhaps better said - I am not a php developer. I have posted the current script I am using, which sends the information I want, but not the COMMENT1 or COMMENT 2.

Also - is there an easy way to have this information in a more easily viewed format - not a huge string but a nice little A=B on each line, for example?